# Using MarkDown on dynamic websites?

Tags: wysiwyg, markdown, rtf, richtext

Do any WYSIWYG **editors** exist that work natively in Markdown? *(any Platform/Language)* 
...So consumers don't have to see the code behind, just work in an MS-Word like interface.

An **assisted** MarkDown editor where you're viewing and editing the Markdown-source (like the one I'm writing this question with) would also be okay.

Comment: been looking for something like this as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large list of [Markdown implementations](http://markdown.infogami.com/) at the Markdown Wiki.

- Perl
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby
- C
- C#
- Java
- Javascript
- Common Lisp
- Lua
- Haskell

And:

- Blog Software
- Wiki Software
- Text Editor
- Desktop Software
- Other Tools

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Wysiwym Markdown Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/demo) (The one we're using here). It shows live-markdown though, rather than masking it. I think the great thing about Markdown is that just about anybody can understand the basics of it.

This is the only editor I know of. After doing a cursory browsing of Google it appears to be one of the few, if not the only one in wide-spread use at the moment.